# Select contact email with ABPeoplePickerNavigationController tries to send email instead

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got an Objective C project using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to select a contact's email address.

Code is like so:

```
-(IBAction)_email_contactsbuttonpushed_orig:(UIButton*)contactsbutton {
[AnalyticsWrapper logEvent:@"share_via_contacts_clicked"];

// ABPeoplePickerNavigationController
_contactPicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
_contactPicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
_contactPicker.delegate = self;


// Define properties to show when viewing a specific person
_contactPicker.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@(kABPersonEmailProperty), nil];

// Style the nav bar
[[QPDrawing shared] paintNavBarInController:_contactPicker];



// showing the picker
if (isIpad) {

    self.peoplePopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_contactPicker];
    _peoplePopoverController.delegate = self;

    CGRect b = self.homeViewController.view.bounds;
    CGRect b2 = (CGRect){
        b.size.width/2-5,0,
        10,self.homeViewController.headerview.bounds.size.height
    };
    b2 = _emailContactsButton.frame;
    b2.origin.y += self.view.frame.origin.y; // push box down to account for header
    [_peoplePopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:b2
                                              inView:self.homeViewController.view
                            permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                            animated:YES];
}
else {

    [self.homeViewController presentViewController:_contactPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
} 
}
```

The popup appears okay, and I can select a contact.
When I select a contact, it opens up the contact detail.
However, when I click on an email address, it switches to the email app and is composing an email -- just as if I had opened my contacts app etc..

The callbacks for peoplePickerNavigationController:didSelectPerson never gets called.

This isn't my code originally, but I'm told it USED to work.  Other developers have worked not he project though, so I don't know if changes were made that broke it or not.  I know PeoplePickerNavigationController is a little dated.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT -- Additional info regarding delegate methods:

shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:

```
// Called after a person has been selected by the user.
// Return YES if you want the person to be displayed.
// Return NO  to do nothing (the delegate is responsible for dismissing the peoplePicker).
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {


_addressbookFirstName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
_addressbookLastName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

// Continue on to the person's details
return YES;
}
```

shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:property:identifier:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {

if ( property != kABPersonEmailProperty ) {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Unless you are trying to support iOS 8, you should be using classes from the newer ContactsUI framework, not the old AddressBookUI framework.

Comment: And using `UIPopoverController` directly just for iPad is pretty out-of-date too.

Comment: If you really want help with this code you need to update your question with your relevant delegate methods.

Comment: I added the delegate methods as you suggested.  I just re-compiled and run with doing UIPopoverController on all devices, but no improvement there.  The picker comes up either way, but no actual picking happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to allow a user to select a contact's email and you want to do something with that email then the only delegate method you need to implement is `peoplePickerNavigationController:didSelectPerson:property:identifier:`.

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
    if (property == kABPersonEmailProperty) {
        // An email property has been selected on person
        ABMultiValueRef ref = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
        CFIndex idx = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(ref, identifier);
        NSString *email = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(ref, idx);
        CFRelease(ref);

        _addressbookFirstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        _addressbookLastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    }
}
```